# get value of HTML th element when clicking on td

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a html table which opens a bootstrap modal when i click on a td of the table.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-sm res-table" id="reservationtable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="theader-text td-border-right"><svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-calendar" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V1h8V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V1h1a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V3a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h1V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zM1 4v10a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h12a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4H1z"/></svg></th>
            <th scope="col" class="theader-text td-border-right" colspan="3"><?php echo "<span class='theader-text-nonstrong'>" . date("l") . "</span><br><span class='theader-date'>" . date("Y-m-d"); ?></span></th>
            <th scope="col" class="theader-text td-border-right" colspan="3"><?php echo "<span class='theader-text-nonstrong'>" . date("l", strtotime("+1 day")). "</span><br><span class='theader-date'>" . date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day")); ?></span></th>
            <th scope="col" class="theader-text td-border-right" colspan="3"><?php echo "<span class='theader-text-nonstrong'>" . date("l", strtotime("+2 day")). "</span><br><span class='theader-date'>" . date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+2 day")); ?></span></th>
            <th scope="col" class="theader-text td-border-right" colspan="3"><?php echo "<span class='theader-text-nonstrong'>" . date("l", strtotime("+3 day")). "</span><br><span class='theader-date'>" . date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+3 day")); ?></span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="td-border-right">Zeit</th>
            <th scope="col">Platz 1</th>
            <th scope="col">Platz 2</th>
            <th scope="col" class="td-border-right">Platz 3</th>
            <th scope="col">Platz 1</th>
            <th scope="col">Platz 2</th>
            <th scope="col" class="td-border-right">Platz 3</th>
            <th scope="col">Platz 1</th>
            <th scope="col">Platz 2</th>
            <th scope="col" class="td-border-right">Platz 3</th>
            <th scope="col">Platz 1</th>
            <th scope="col">Platz 2</th>
            <th scope="col" class="td-border-right">Platz 3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="td-border-right">08:00</th>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="td-border-right"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="td-border-right"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="td-border-right"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="td-border-right"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="td-border-right">09:00</th>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="td-border-right"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="td-border-right"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="td-border-right"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="td-border-right"></td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

My jquery file currently looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
let spanHeadings = [];

$('thead th[colspan]').each(function(){
    const colspan = +this.colSpan,
        heading = $(this).find('.theader-date').text();
    // create as many headings as colspan length
    spanHeadings.push.apply(spanHeadings, Array(colspan).fill(heading));
});

$('#reservationtable tbody td').on('click', function () {
    var reservationtime = $( this ).siblings('th').text();
    const tdIdx = $(this).index() - 1;
    const heading = spanHeadings[tdIdx];
    const court = courtHeadings[tdIdx];
    $('#modalvon').text(reservationtime);
    $('#modalbis').text(addMinutes(reservationtime, '60'));
    $('#modaldatum').text(heading);
    $('#modalcourt').text(#CODE TO GET CORRECT COLUMN TH#);
    $("#confirmreservierung").modal("show");
});
```

});

Now i want to get the correct column th of the clicked td like "Platz 1", "Platz 2" or "Platz 3" and load it into the `$('#modalcourt').text(#CODE TO GET CORRECT COLUMN TH#);` bootstrap modal with this function. If i try to change the function which stores all day-columns as an array

```
$('thead th[colspan]').each(function(){
const colspan = +this.colSpan,
    heading = $(this).find('.theader-date').text();
// create as many headings as colspan length
spanHeadings.push.apply(spanHeadings, Array(colspan).fill(heading));
```

})

then i don't know what i should change `$('thead th[colspan]')` here to get access to the other th elements which are not in the thead and don't have the scope="row"

How can i do this?

Comment: This question was also asked by me but the answers given don't work in this case and i don't know how to do it

Comment: I already know it is asked by you :) I think you should have another (and deep) look at the documentation of jQuery.

Comment: @Gulaschsuppe123 *but the answers given don't work in this case* => If the answer does not work - that does not mean you need to post another question with same requirements - since it will considered as duplicate questions - but rather get the answer from the previous question. You have `accepted` that answer that mean it solved your issue :)

Comment: @HarunYilmaz could you please help me with this problem?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping It solved my issue for another problem, but this problem is different.

Comment: So now you want to load the `text` of `clicked` td element in each platz in the `modalCourt` ?

Comment: If you have a mix of th with/without colspan then use `$('thead th`) not `$('thead th[colspan]`) to determine the th's - then `this.colSpan` needs to check if it has a colspan and add 1 if it doesn't

Comment: Unfortunately you did not clarify earlier that this question is different then the last one but rather you said *the answers given don't work in this case* - this question was market as `duplicate` of the previous one and is `closed` now. - the quesiton share the exact same details with no to little difference at all.

Comment: I'll agree (again) with @AlwaysHelping here - if your other question's answer isn't quite correct for your original scenario, so you shouldn't have accepted it and should have asked for more info on that answer.

Comment: But then i would "overblow" the old question because this requires a different answer. It only has the same html table

Comment: As worded (now) it's hard to tell what you're asking - *"to get access to the other th not in the thead"* - **so it may (now) be a different question**, but I'm assuming was *originally* (I've not trawled edit history) worded to be close enough that people thought it was the same.

Comment: Okay im sorry i use Stackoverflow for the first time today to ask a question. But could you please help me?

Comment: There is not much difference to what you want now. I am sure the person who answered previous one would be happy to have helped you to be honest to compile all code in one answer since Its the SAME table and data :) :)

Comment: It's a difficult line, asking follow-on questions is generally advised rather than adding more to the original question after it's been answered - but only if the original answer solves the original question (which it's now hard to tell if it did).  While equally if it's a "not-quite-fit" most answerers will extend to help out.  Hard to tell which the case here is - the edits make it look like a follow-on question, but the comments (and I guess original) make it look like original answer was not correct.  Good luck :)